# Каверзные вопросы

Tags: частица-не

-Ты меня не любишь?
-Нет.

значит ли это, что ответчик на самом деле сказал "нет, не люблю" или "нет, люблю".
то есть, я думаю, что если на заданный вопрос ответили просто "нет", то это означает "нет, я тебя не люблю".

скажите, что будет вернее?

Answer (score 1):

Возможные ответы:

1. Люблю
2. Не люблю
3. Да, не люблю
4. Нет, не люблю
5. Нет, люблю.
6. Нет (что означает "не люблю")

А ответы "да" или "да, люблю" невозможны.

Comment: Почему невозможен ответ "да"? Вполне возможен. "-Ты меня не любишь? - Да!"

Answer (score 0):

Гм... Ну, вообще-то, мне бы мне так ответили, я бы расценила это как "нет, не люблю". Хотя, тут, конечно, зависит и от интонации, с которой это произнесено. И, если это все из какого-то литературного произведения, то автор обычно объясняет, что имелось в виду. Либо он бы конкретизировал ответ: "нет, не люблю".

Comment: таки расценивать "нет" как "нет, не люблю"?

Comment: Так и расценивайте.